# What is the pattern to match complete input in Logstash?

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, elastic-stack

I am using ELK stack with filebeat.

**filebeat.conf**

```
filebeat:
  prospectors:
    -
      paths:
        - /home/ubuntu/logs_*
      input_type: log
output:
  logstash:
    hosts: [${LOGSTASH_PORT_5044_TCP_ADDR}]
    index: filebeat
  console:
    pretty: true
```

This is passing logs from a file *logs_test*

A sample log

```
{"name":"test","statusCode":0,"deployment":"production","hostname":"ip-random-address","level":30,"jobName":"testJob","date":"2016-07-18T03:15:02.075Z","jobType":"script","msg":"","time":"2016-07-18T03:15:02.076Z","v":0}
```

I want to make a HTTP call to an external URL when the field statusCode is 1

The entire log object is being passed to logstash.

My **logstash config**

```
input {
    beats { 
        port => 5044
        codec => "json"
    }
}



output {
  if ([statusCode] and [statusCode] == 1) {
        http {
            format=>"message"
            http_method=>"post"
            url=>"http://www.example.com"
            message=>'{"text": "%{some_pattern_matcher}"}'
             }
      }
}
```

[Question] What should the *"some_pattern_matcher"* be to send all fields to HTTP request.

PS: %{mesage} does not work.

Comment: have you tried %{source}?

Answer (score 0):

```
input {
    beats { 
        port => 5044
        codec => "json"
    }
}
filter{
     grok{
          match => { "message" => "%{GREEDYDATA:data}" }
     }
}
output {
  if ([statusCode] and [statusCode] == 1) {
        http {
            format=>"message"
            http_method=>"post"
            url=>"http://www.example.com"
            message=> %{data}
           }
      }
}
```

I haven't tried it out. So try this one and let me know if this solution works. If not please post the error(s) you got.

Comment: sure, let me try. trying that %{source} first.

Comment: I think it should be "%{data}". If this doesn't work too then we can think of another approach.

Comment: I actually tried "%{data}", as I was having other fields which worked this way "%{fieldName}". but, "%{data}" did not work.